# GetItems with CAML against lookup on online throws "list view threshold"-error

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, list-view-threshold

I want to query for items where a lookup has a title which contains some text.
The list has over 5000 items, but the query result will return fewer, so it should work.

This query works, querying for title:

```
<Contains><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>test</Value></Contains>
```

This query does *not* work, querying a lookup:

```
<Contains><FieldRef Name='MyLookup' /><Value Type='Lookup'>test</Value></Contains>
```

Both fields are indexed. I don't want to first fetch IDs for the lookup list items (`LookupId` works, but only on ID). I have tried `Type='Text'`. I have tried with `<Eq>`.

Comment: Filtering with lookup on a list with over 5k items works with REST api weirdly but not CAML Query...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `<Contains>` with `Lookup` columns. Only `Text` and `Note` field types are supported.

See this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms196501.aspx).

Comment: It works if the list has less than 5000 items, so I think works.

Comment: Contains isn't indexed, the UI tells you this when you try to create a view, so it stands to reason that it would fail once you go over 5000.

Comment: @EricAlexander Isn't it the field which is indexed, and not the query part? And if `<Contains>` is not indexed, why does it work with Title?

Answer (score -1):

Include your query inside a Where clause/tag.

```
<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='MyLookup' /><Value Type='Lookup'>test</Value></Contains></Where>
```

Comment: Yes I also need a View, since I use CSOM. Sorry I should have mentioned this, but since I mention my first example works it was proof enough the surround bits are in place.

Comment: can you please explain me a bit more & if you can send me a entire line than it would be a great to understand

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it any better. But I've thrown together a quick example for you here: https://gist.github.com/eirikb/8e71c5cb31b4d64f779cbcd7b3b06692
It's using JSOM, whilst I actually use CSOM, but it's the same result.

Comment: You may get solution from http://shareyourpoint.net/2015/07/21/how-to-deal-with-query-throttling-in-sharepoint/

Comment: I'm not sure how that link helps? You mean the core problem is on a higher level (e.g., structural, search, etc)? I see `QueryThrottleMode` is mentioned, but I don't think this works with CSOM (it's for `SPQuery`, not `CamlQuery`).